# Upgrade to High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra

I currently run MacOS 10.12.4 Sierra on a mid-2011 iMac.  I want to upgrade to 10.13 High Sierra.  On the App Store, the only option (after Sept 24) is 10.14 Mojave.  Where should I go to get High Sierra?  If I go to https://support.apple.com/en_AU/downloads/macos,  there are many different download options, but they all are updates, such as 10.13.6.

Answer (score 1):

[macOS High Sierra Download Link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?ls=1&mt=12)

That link should permit you to download the full macOS High Sierra installer from the App Store.